# Can't access to the web application inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I build an Web application using Node.js that will use Port 5000,then I try to put them inside a docker. This is my Dockerfile

```
#Using node image from Docker Hub
FROM node:10
#App Directory inside Docker container
WORKDIR /app
#Copy all files into the container
COPY . .
#Install dependencies
RUN npm install
#Open Application port
EXPOSE 5000
#Build application
RUN npm run build
#Start application
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

When I tried to build the image, it work normally as below

```
sudo docker build -t testing:1.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.083MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:10
 ---> 7e5086278377
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6c293598724f
Step 3/7 : COPY . .
 ---> ce04776bf49a
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 12fa143fb099

added 243 packages from 227 contributors and audited 244 packages in 20.077s

6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing intermediate container 12fa143fb099
 ---> 20163c2cdfba
Step 5/7 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in b4613d4064eb

> testing@0.7.2 build /app
> rollup -c


src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
created public/build/bundle.js in 11.3s
Removing intermediate container b4613d4064eb
 ---> cae7c7cb71c2
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Running in ece8e808d698
Removing intermediate container ece8e808d698
 ---> 58b2af470419
Step 7/7 : CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
 ---> Running in 9ec9f771412c
Removing intermediate container 9ec9f771412c
 ---> 7ddb7391497c
Successfully built 7ddb7391497c
Successfully tagged testing:1.0
```

After that, I tried to create a container using that image above and port it to 5001 on my machine

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5001:5000 testing:1.0
```

However, I can't connect to the web application using **http://localhost:5001/**.

To test and make sure the container work and create the web application,I also come inside the docker and try to create another web application using the same port 5000 to make sure that the container already create the web application for that port. You guys can check inside this link [URL to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8S0F.png)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong :(. If you guys need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your application is actually listening on port 5000? What happens if you connecto `http://<the_address_of_your_container>:5000`? Do the logs from your container indicate that there are any problems?

Comment: I tried to connect to the actual IP of the container ```https://172.17.0.2:5001/```, and I still don't see anything ....
https://imgur.com/AL7sXaF

Comment: What does `yarn start` actually do?  If you're running an Express application, do you explicitly set it to listen on only 127.0.0.1 (which would cause this issue)?

Comment: According to what you've posted in  your question, the service in the container is running on port `5000`, not `5001`.